# laravel filter return all the records

Tags: php, mysql, search, laravel-8

im trying to search using three inputs, in the first scenario when i search using all the inputs it return the result, in the second scenrio when i search by using only one field it return all the records what im trying to do is when i search with one field it return a specsific result,

```
public function multiSearch(Request $request){
        $search   = $request->input('search');
        $search_1 = $request->input('search_1');
        $search_2 = $request->input('search_2');
        $cars = Car::query()
            ->where('price', 'LIKE', "%{$search}%")
            ->orWhere('model', 'LIKE', "%{$search_1}%")
            ->orWhere('transmission', 'LIKE', "%{$search_2}%")
        ->get();

        return view('car.car-multisearch', ['cars'=>$cars]);
    }
```

this is my blade code

```
<form type="get" action="{{url('/search-car')}}">
  @csrf
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
            <p>
               <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Price" />
            </p>
     </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>
          <input type="text" name="search_1" placeholder="Model Year" />
         </p> 
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <p>
          <select name="search_2">
              <option  data-display="Transmission">Transmission</option>
              <option value="Automatic">Automatic</option>
             <option value="Manual">Manual</option>
          </select>
        </p>
        </div>
      <button type="submit" class="gauto-theme-btn">Find Car</button>
   </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can dynamically add where statements to your query depending on [values presence in the request and if they are not empty](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/requests#determining-if-input-is-present). Example:

```
public function multiSearch(Request $request){
    $cars = Car::query();
    
    if ( $request->filled('search') ) {
        $cars->where('price', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('search')}%");
    }

    if ( $request->filled('search_1') ) {
        $cars->orWhere('model', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('search_1')}%");
    }

    if ( $request->filled('search_2') ) {
        $cars->orWhere('transmission', 'LIKE', "%{$request->input('search_2')}%");
    }

    return view('car.car-multisearch', ['cars'=> $cars->get() ]);
}
```

This solution do the job, but looks not good because you will need to add more if statements for each filter.)